# CSS show shadow if it's more than 130px from top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I do the next javascript function using CSS only? 
I need to show box-shadow if it's more than 130 pixels from top of the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 130) {
        $('.shadow').css({
                'box-shadow': 'none',
                '-moz-box-shadow' : 'none',
                '-webkit-box-shadow' : 'none' });
    }
    else {
        $('.shadow').css({
                'box-shadow': '0px 10px 10px #d0d0d0',
                '-moz-box-shadow' : '0px 10px 10px #d0d0d0',
                '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0px 10px 10px #d0d0d0' });
    }    
});
```

I really have to do this only in CSS for my job application. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to show box-shadow if it's more than 130 pixels from top of the page.

Comment: I'd suggest amending your question to reflect that. You'll get more appropriate responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 130  || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 130 ) {
        document.getElementById("myBtnd").classList.add("showbox");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtnd").classList.remove("showbox");
      }
    }
```

**css**

```
.showbox{

 box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px 10px #888888;
}
```

Comment: This is practically the same function. I said that I need to do this using ONLY CSS, WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT!